# Does only custom post type have post type archive pages?

Tags: archives, post-type

`is_post_type_archive (string|array $post_types = '' )`
Is the query for existing post type archive page?

Reference: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_post_type_archive/

I search on WordPress and Google for *post type archive* I only see *custom post type archive* article. Does only *custom post type* have *post type archive page*?

The WordPress internal post type like `post`, `page`, `attachment` and so on doen't have a *post type archive page*? If they have, how can I access the page?

Answer (score 1):

There is no archive pages for the build in post types, only for custom post types when `has_archive` is set.

In general, the homepage is accepted to be the archive page for the post type `post`, but it is not an official archive page in the sense of custom post type archive pages.

You can create archive pages for the build in post types, but that will require some kind of rewrite rules and custom URL structure